# How to create GSON converter with int and string

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Hello i face a problem with create a GSON converter to retrofit 2

On Api in "value" section i got two possible parameters, int and String.

So as you know sometimes, when i download a String(except of int) i got error like:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "JACK"

Im trying to create a GSON converter to prevent JSON getting this error, but i cant realize it.

I trying do this with method:

```
public class StringTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {


@Override
public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
    if (Objects.equals(value, "ACE")) {
        value= String.valueOf(1);
        return;
    }
    out.value(value);
}

@Override
public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if(in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL){
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
    }
    String stringValue = in.nextString();
    try{
        return String.valueOf(stringValue);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

but this not work.

What i excepted.

I want to give values
when

```
"ACE" = 1
"KING" = 2
"QUEEN" = 3
"JACK" = 4
```

Can someone help me?

this is my class Card:

```
public class Card {

    private String image;
    private int value;
    private String suit;
    private String code;
}
```

Here is example of JSON

```
{
"success": true,
"cards": [
    {
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/KH.png",
        "value": "KING",
        "suit": "HEARTS",
        "code": "KH"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/8C.png",
        "value": "8",
        "suit": "CLUBS",
        "code": "8C"
    }
],
"deck_id":"3p40paa87x90",
"remaining": 50
```

}

I declared this class here:

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringTypeAdapter()).create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: Have you registered this TypeAdapter?

Comment: please check edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a king clash with a two, doesn't it? Anyway. You seem just not need custom adapters: you just need proper mappings. First off, when you define a type adapter, you have to be aware that you override *all* type usages. Thus, when you define a string type adapter, it affects *all* strings. Second, when you have a finite number of elements like card suits and card ranks, you can use enums:

```java
enum Suit {

    @SuppressWarnings("SPADES") SPADES,
    @SerializedName("HEARTS") HEARTS,
    @SuppressWarnings("DIAMONDS") DIAMONDS,
    @SerializedName("CLUBS") CLUBS

}
```

```java
enum Rank {

    @SerializedName("ACE") ACE,
    @SerializedName("KING") KING,
    @SerializedName("QUEEN") QUEEN,
    @SerializedName("JACK") JACK,
    @SerializedName("10") TEN,
    @SerializedName("9") NINE,
    @SerializedName("8") EIGHT,
    @SerializedName("7") SEVEN,
    @SerializedName("6") SIX,
    @SerializedName("5") FIVE,
    @SerializedName("4") FOUR,
    @SerializedName("3") THREE,
    @SerializedName("2") TWO

}
```

So the rest of your mappings may be implemented as follows:

```java
final class Card {

    @SerializedName("image") final URL image = null;
    @SerializedName("value") final Rank rank = null;
    @SerializedName("suit") final Suit suit = null;
    @SerializedName("code") final String code = null;

}
```

Note that all fields are now strongly typed. Also you can make `Rank` return a `code` your need (just add a specific code field to the enum and initialize it via the enum constructor). If for any solid reason you need an `int` field, you better annotate the field with `@JsonAdapter` to let it be more specific:

```java
final class Card {

    @SerializedName("image") final URL image = null;
    @SerializedName("value") @JsonAdapter(RankTypeAdapter.class) final int rank = Integet.valueOf(0);
    @SerializedName("suit") final Suit suit = null;
    @SerializedName("code") final String code = null;

}
```

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

final class RankTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Integer> {

    private static final List<String> ranks = asList("ACE", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING");

    private RankTypeAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Integer value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final String rank = in.nextString();
        final int index = ranks.indexOf(rank);
        if ( index == -1 ) {
            throw new MalformedJsonException("Cannot parse: " + rank + " at " + in);
        }
        return index + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just change the list for rivate static final List<String> ranks = asList("ACE", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
            "9", "10", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING");
I think you know why :)

Have a nice day :D

Comment: @Rodriquez, it depends regarding various games, but yeah I think that making the ace the lowest card rank can be easily changed according to the rules of a particular game on demand. Please feel free to edit my answer as I'm not at my desktop at the moment. Thanks for keeping a sharp eye. :)